# Gson().toJson(this) not working properly

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to convert my object into String via GSON library. 
I write like this: Gson().toJson(this) and `String` I receive is not full.
This is my "this" object:

[image: http://i.snag.gy/LgXrw.jpg]

As you can see, it has accuracy field(result -> tracks->points->accuracy)
But when I execute this Gson().toJson(this), I got string without this field. What's wrong with it?

```
{
"carId": 14,
"closed": 1442409732,
"commentEnd": "оо",
"guid": "bbc329e4-65c5-4b16-91d5-45283ca9dcb7",
"isDeleted": false,
"lastUpdate": 0,
"litersEnd": -23.1,
"litersStart": -23.1,
"number": 0,
"odometrEnd": 25,
"odometrStart": 44,
"opened": 1442409723,
"id": 0,
"status": 2,
"Tracks": [
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "closed": 1442409729,
        "commentEnd": "рр",
        "distance": 0,
        "guid": "aba4de4a-5bc7-49fc-a537-b8da3dd17783",
        "opened": 1442409723,
        "points": [
            {
                "dateCreated": 1442409725,
                "guid": 579,
                "lat": 56.8408432,
                "lng": 53.2100482
            }
        ],
        "id": 0,
        "statusNumber": 2
    }
],
```

}

My class for Point object looked like that(just declaration of variables:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "points")
public class Point implements Serializable {

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
@SerializedName("guid")
long id;
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "trackId")
transient Track track;
@DatabaseField
double lat;
@DatabaseField
double lng;
@DatabaseField
long dateCreated;
@DatabaseField
transient float accuracy; //this field is faulty
transient String provider;

public Point() {}

public Point(double lat, double lng, long dateCreated) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated / 1000L;
}
```

}

and **Point** was a field of **Track** object which was a field of **DrivingList** object, which extended **Uploadable** abstract class in which I run this code:

```
public abstract class Uploadable {

public String toJson() {
    return new Gson().toJson(this);
}
```

Comment: We will be unable to help you if you don't post any code. Please [edit] your post to include more code.

Comment: make sure the field is not `transient`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this field in my class was transient.

The transient keyword in Java is used to indicate that a field should not be serialized.

Comment: Is this answer to your question??

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya It would result in what alex is seeing, so probably.

Comment: seems like my suspicion was well placed; good job and good job for answering your own question (y)
+1

Comment: @durron597 Actually Alex does not provided full info in question like java code so its a kind of false question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

my json data is like

```
{"name":"naval","edu":"pg","gender":"male"}
```

so my model class which will store the value of json data should be like this

```
public class Model
{
 String name,edu,gender;
 public String getName()
{
return name;
}
public String getEdu()
{
return edu;
}
public String getGender()
{
return gender;
}
public String setGender(String gender)
{
this.gender=gender;
}
public String setName(String name)
{
this.name=name;
}
public String setEdu(String edu)
{
this.edu=edu;
}

 }
```

the place where we want  json data will be Streamed or downloaded 
at that  place write this code

```
String strJson=getjsonString();//your method to get jsondata as string
```

or  as for local test case

```
  strJson="{\"name\":\"naval\",\"edu\":\"pg\",\"gender\":\"male\"}";//this is for demo   
Gson gson=new Gson();
Model model = gson.fromJson(strJson,Model.class);    System.out.println(model.getName()+","+model.getEdu()+","+model.getGender());
```

this will print like this

```
naval,pg,male
```

to prase the json into model class
when you want to convert the class object to jsonString use this

```
Model modelInfo =new Model();
modelInfo.setName("Vijay");model.setEdu("B.tech");
String strJsonobj=gson.toJson(modelInfo);
System.out.println(strJSONOBJ);
```

IT WILL print like this json

```
{"name":"Vijay","edu":"B.tech","gender":"null"}
```

as you can see that variable which is not set is comming as null the default value
or if json will have extra data which is not there in class it will be discarted and which is there will be set there respective value